# how to insert name of a variable and its result into a plot in R

Tags: r

I have two variables that I'd like to show on the side of a plot that I've already created, alongside their results

```
London <- nrow()
NewYork <- nrow()
London
[1] 22
NewYork
[1] 10
```

This is what I've tried

```
PreviousPlot + labs(legend = London , NewYork)
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: There's an `annotate` function. Usage" `p + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = "Some text")`

Answer (score 1):

```
London = 22
NewYork = 10

graphics.off()
plot(1, 1)
legend("topright", legend = c(bquote(.(London)), bquote(.(NewYork))))
```